# Как добавить объект формата glTF на сцену?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Пытаюсь добавить 3д объект на сцену.

Ошибка
Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor ol cannot be invoked without 'new' at new GLTFLoader

Делаю пост этого вопроса второй раз (извиняюсь). Часть ошибок исправил и понял, что главная ошибка в строке

```
let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
```

Но не могу понять, что нужно засунуть в скобки? new ?.., или что?
Спасибо.

Моделька 2(МБ): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bPnC5coazNFIcsyvV9U29BFiFhXhriYg/view?usp=sharing

Исходный код:

```js
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 10; // Отдаление камеры

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
renderer.setSize(1280, 720);

renderer.domElement.setAttribute("id", "Church3DObj");
document.body.insertBefore(renderer.domElement, document.body.firstChild);

const aLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 1.2);
scene.add(aLight);

let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
let obj = null;

loader.load('/3d/Church.gltf', function(gltf) {
  obj = gltf;
  obj.scene.scale.set(1.3, 1.3, 1.3);

  scene.add(obj.scene);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
```

Comment: В приведенном вами примере нету ошибки, про которой вы говорите.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, возможно. Но тогда в чём она. Я пытаюсь руководствоваться  этим сайтом: https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader.

Если верить ему, то я должен использовать const loader = new GLTFLoader();, но тогда я ловлю ошибку: Unresolved type GLTFLoader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Что бы избежать этой ошибки мы должны скачать с [GitHub](https://threejs.org) файлы .js:

three.js, GLTFLoader.js, OrbitControls.js, three.module.js

```
<script src="scripts/three.js"></script> 
<script type="module"> src="scripts/GLTFLoader.js"></script> 
<script type="module"> src="scripts/OrbitControls.js"></script>// ЕСЛИ ЕСТЬ УПРАВЛЕНИЕ КАМЕРОЙ В ПРОСТРАНСТВЕ
```

Помещаем их в корень с проектом и открываем GLTFLoader.js. В момент 24.05.2021 находим 64 строку

```
from './smthPath/smthPath/smthPath/three.module.js';
```

и удаляем лишнее. (то есть указываем путь к файлу three.module.js). В моём случае:

```
from './three.module.js';
```

(Если есть управление камерой, то делаем тоже самое с файлом OrbitControls.js 9 строка)

```
from './three.module.js';
```

Далее ВАЖНО в скрипт, в котором все мозги добавляем type = "module", и импортим файлы - то есть получается

```
<script type="module">

import {GLTFLoader} from "./scripts/GLTFLoader.js";
import {OrbitControls} from './scripts/OrbitControls.js';

//...
</script>
```

***ВАЖНО***

*Для людей, которые не работали с 3Д в веб, но моделят в Cinema4D, 3Ds Max, ZBrush... (как я). Вам нужны не только файл .gltf, но и .bin
Как их получить?

1. Заходим на сайт [Scetchfab](https://sketchfab.com/feed).
2. Загружаем модель (ставим настройки бесплатное скачивание (потом
   можно удалить модельку)).
3. Ждём, пока она обработается.
4. качаем нужный формат (glFT)
5. Удаляем модельку с Scetchfab`а*

***ВАЖНО***

***Конечный вид html файла***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dragon</title>

</head>
<body id="c" style="margin: 0;">

<!--3D-->
<script src="scripts/three.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="scripts/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="scripts/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<script type="module">
    import {GLTFLoader} from "./scripts/GLTFLoader.js";
    import {OrbitControls} from './scripts/OrbitControls.js';

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x555555);

    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
    camera.position.set(0, 5, 15);

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true, antialias: true});
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
    renderer.setSize(1920 , 1080);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);



    const aLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 15);
    aLight.position.set(0,10,10)
    scene.add(aLight);

    const pLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 15);
    pLight.position.set(0,5,0)
    scene.add(pLight);

    const phelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper(pLight);
    scene.add(phelper);


    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    let obj = null;




    loader.load("3d/Dragon/scene.gltf", function(gltf) {
        obj = gltf.scene;
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
    });


    const canvas = document.getElementById("c");
    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
    controls.target.set(0, 1, 0);
    controls.update();

    function animate(){
        requestAnimationFrame(animate)
        obj.rotation.y += 0.005;
        renderer.render(scene, camera)
    }
    animate();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для начала нужно быть уверенным, что все используемые модули фреймворка из одной и той же версии/ревизии (текущая r128).

Использовал модель из дистрибутива - все работает, как ожидалось.

Модель, которую предполагается загружать, хорошо бы проверить на сайте https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/. Если там она не грузится - значит, что-то не так с файлом (файлами) модели.

```js
let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 3; // Отдаление камеры

let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor(0x404040);
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);

renderer.domElement.setAttribute("id", "Church3DObj");
document.body.insertBefore(renderer.domElement, document.body.firstChild);

let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

const aLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.5);
aLight.position.setScalar(10);
scene.add(aLight, new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));

let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
let obj = null;

loader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/models/gltf/DamagedHelmet/glTF/DamagedHelmet.gltf', function(gltf) {
  obj = gltf.scene;
  scene.add(obj);
});

renderer.setAnimationLoop(_ => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
})
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.128.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.128.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.128.0/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
```